# In C++, initialize a class member with 'this' pointer during construction

Tags: c++, class, initialization, this

I'd like to create a class that is associated to another class in some sort of parent-child relationship. For this the "child" class needs a reference to it's parent.

For example:

```
template <typename T>
class TEvent {
    private: T* Owner;
    public: TEvent(T* parent) : Owner(parent) {}
};

class Foo {
    private: TEvent<Foo> Froozle; // see below
};
```

Now the problem is that I can't initialize the `Froozle` instance directly, nor using the instanciation list of Foo's constructor, because `this` references are not allowed there. Apart from adding another method `setParent(T*)` (which I don't like too much because it means that I have to leave the `TEvent<>` instance in an invalid state), is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is OK to use `this` in the initialization list, as long as it is not used to access any members that may not have been initialized yet.

Comment: What he says. As long as the objects you pass `this` to "know" not to touch it during their construction (because the object `this` refers to isn't fully constructed at that moment), doing so is fine, even though some compilers (notably VC) emit a warning for it.

Comment: VC++ is the key point here. It works indeed. Seems like I have to suppress that "error" forcibly. Thanks alot!

Comment: I wish VC++ only emit warning when the member of "this" inside the ctor accessed. BTW, google::LogMessage class in [google-glog](http://code.google.com/p/google-glog) stores "this" to itself in mem-initializer list of ctor for debug purpose. I had to recompile with #pragma warning (4355 :disabled) to make it work in VC2010.

Answer (score 12):

From the standard 12.6.2/7 "Initializing bases and members" (emphasis mine):

> Names in the expression-list of a
>   mem-initializer are evaluated in the
>   scope of the constructor for which the
>   mem-initializer is specified.
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> class X {
>     int a;
>     int b;
>     int i;
>     int j;
>
> public:
>     const int& r;
>     X(int i): r(a), b(i), i(i), j(this->i) {}
> };
> ```
>
> initializes `X::r` to refer to `X::a`,
>   initializes `X::b` with the value of the
>   constructor parameter `i`, initializes
>   `X::i` with  the  value  of  the 
>   constructor  parameter `i`,  and 
>   initializes `X::j` with  the  value  of
>   `X::i`;  this takes place each time an
>   object of `class X` is created.  ]
>
> **[Note: because the mem-initializer are
>   evaluated in the  scope  of  the 
>   constructor,  the `this` pointer  can 
>   be  used  in  the expression-list of 
>   a mem-initializer to refer to the
>   object being initialized.  ]**

Comment: Does this mean that "this" is only allowed in mem-initializer list of ctor or is it also allowed in the body of ctor ? I've tried using "this" inside the body of ctor in VC2010++ several times and it all compiles and runs fine with warning C4355 disabled but just because it works doesnt mean that I'm allowed to. Until now, I haven't found any in the [open-standard doc](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) which states whether it's allowed to refer to "this" inside the body of ctor or not.

Comment: @DavidLee: inside the constructor, `this` points to the object being constructed (just as in the initializer list as described above). You can definitely use `this` inside the constructor body.

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to work; in fact,

```
template<class T>
class Child {
private:
    T *parent;
public:
    Child(T *parent) : parent(parent) {}
};
class Parent {
private:
    Child<Parent> child;
public:
    Parent() : child(this) {}
};
```

compiles fine for me with both g++ 4.4.5 and clang++ 2.8.

What is failing for you?

Comment: The 'treat warnings as errors' compiler flag of VC and the MSDN documentation header that says "Error Message". :) You're absolutely right - It works, I just didn't see it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's failing on you, unless you have the warning level set to 4 (or similar, I assume Visual Studio) and have enabled "treat warnings as errors".

Basically, this warning is A Good Thing, since it won't let you accidentally *use* the `this` pointer when what it points at is yet to be constructed.

However, when you know what you are doing wherever `this` is passed in the initialization list, the warning and error caused by this will be annoying.

You can get rid of it (again, assuming Visual Studio) by decorating the constructor (unless it's defined in the class declaration - then you must decorate all the class):

```
// warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable : 4355)
some_class::some_class()
: ...
{
}
#pragma warning (pop)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to suppress the warning, just do this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() :
    Froozle(get_this())
    {}

private:
    Foo* get_this()
    {
        return this;
    }

    TEvent<Foo> Froozle; // see below
};
```

The indirection is enough to stop it.

Comment: Heh.  Why is a method call okay but a direct reference not?  Silly compiler :)