# Is it safe to use the "this" pointer in an initialization list?

Tags: c++, initialization, this

I have two classes with a parent-child relationship (the `Parent` class "has-a" `Child` class), and the `Child` class has a pointer back to the `Parent`. It would be nice to initialize the parent pointer upon construction of the child, as follows:

```
class Child;
class Parent;

class Child
{
public:
 Child (Parent* parent_ptr_) : parent_ptr(parent_ptr_) {};

private:
 Parent* parent_ptr;
};

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() : child(this) {};

private:
    Child child;
}
```

Now, I know people recommend not using `this` in initialization list, and [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) says I'm gonna get a compiler warning (BTW, on VS2010, I don't get a warning), but I really like this better then calling some set function in `Parent`'s constructor. My questions are:

- Is the parent `this` pointer well-defined when the `Child` object is being created?
- If so, why is it considered bad practice to use it as above?

Thanks,

Boaz

**EDIT:** Thanks Timbo, it is indeed a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006160/in-c-initialize-a-class-member-with-this-pointer-during-construction) (huh, I even chose the same class names). So lets get some added value: how about references? Is it possible / safe to do the following? :

```
class Child
{
public:
 Child (Parent& parnet_ptr_) : parent_ptr(parent_ptr_) {};

private:
 Parent* parent_ptr;
};

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() : child(*this) {};

private:
    Child child;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++, initialize a class member with 'this' pointer during construction.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006160/in-c-initialize-a-class-member-with-this-pointer-during-construction)

Comment: @thecoshman - pun intended?

Comment: vs2010 actually does produce warning on this, it depends on warning level that was set

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes. It's safe to use `this` pointer in initialization-list **as long as it's not being used to access uninitialized members or virtual functions, directly or indirectly**, as the object is not yet fully constructed. The object `child` can store the `this` pointer of `Parent` for later use!

Comment: It's also unsafe to call virtual functions in the parent before the parent's construction is finished.

Comment: In short. The child **CAN NOT** use this pointer in its constructor/destructor but otherwise it is OK.

Comment: does this in turn imply that it is fine to use it to access already initialized members? For example `struct foo { int x,y;  foo(int z) : x(z), y(this->x) {} };` or how about using `this` to refer to the member as in this case: `struct foo { int x; foo(int z) : this->x(z) {} };` ?

Comment: `y(this->x)` is perfectly fine. and why would you do `this->x(z)` though when `x(z)` is enough and means the same thing? I dont even know if the compiler would allow you to write `this->x(z)`.

Comment: It appears `this->x(z)` is invalid.  It would have been useful if the member variable shares the same name as a constructor argument, which is quite common.  I.e. `this->x(x)` instead of `x(x)`

Comment: In the init-list, you cannot use `this`. So use `x(x)`, not `this->x(x)`. [Note that `x(x)` is correct, the compiler knows which `x` is param and which `x` is member, so will do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185043/415784)

Answer (score 14):

The parent `this` pointer, in "pointer terms", *is* well-defined (otherwise how would the parent constructor know on which instance is it operating?), but:

- the fields that are declared after the `Child` object aren't initialized yet;
- the code in the constructor hasn't run yet;
- also, the usual warnings about using virtual members from the constructor apply<sup>1</sup>.

So, the parent object in general is still in an inconsistent state; everything the child object will do on construction on the parent object, will be done on a half-constructed object, and this in general isn't a good thing (e.g. if it calls "normal" methods - that rely on the fact that the object is fully constructed - you may get in "impossible" code paths).

Still, if all the child object do with the parent pointer in its constructor is to store it to be use it later (=> when it will be actually constructed), there's nothing wrong with it.

---

1. I.e., virtual dispatch doesn't work in constructors, because the vtable hasn't been updated yet by the derived class constructor. See e.g. [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html).

Comment: @Matteo Italia : +1. By the way, why did you keep third point in parentheses? That is as important as others. Remove the parentheses!

Comment: @Nawaz: thank you, parentheses removed (BTW, you too got my +1 before I started writing `:)`). The parens were there because it wasn't a warning *specific* to this scenario, but general about virtual functions and constructors; it was a "just in case you didn't remember it" advice. `:)`

Comment: Question - is it the order of field declarations, or the order of initialisers, that is significant? I thought the latter (where they are present), but it's been a while since I worried about it.

Comment: @Steve: ((I think you're correct))(Or maybe, I do (not) think the (way) you think).

Comment: @Steve314: it's the order of field declarations, not of the initializers. Actually, if you specify different orders most compilers (in "paranoid warnings mode") will issue a warning that reminds you this.

Comment: @Matteo - thanks. @Nawaz - No-one thinks the way I think! Why would anyone want to?

Comment: @Steve, @Nawaz: probably you two have different overloads of the parentheses (function call) operators. :S

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour is well-defined so long as you don't attempt to dereference the pointer until *after* the `Parent` object has been completely constructed (as @Sergey says in a comment below, if the object being constructed is actually derived from `Parent`, then *all* of its constructors must have completed).

Comment: Not exactly the Parent constructor. Strictly speaking, accessing the pointer freely is only guaranteed to be safe after all the object's constructors have completed. In the Parent constructor we have no way to know if it's actually a Parent being constructed or possibly some distant subclass of it that has its fields and possibly reimplements some virtual functions defined in the Parent.

Comment: @Sergey: That's a *very* good point.  I will update my answer.