# Check in constructor vs. set function

Tags: c++, validation, constructor

this is a very simple question. Suppose I have a class

```
class A
{
public:
  A(int);
  void setA(int);
private:
  int a;
};
```

with implementation

```
A::A(int a_) : a(a_) { }
void A::setA(int a_) { a = a_; }
```

Let's say I want to avoid having `a = 0` but I don't want to throw an exception, I just want to keep a valid object with `a = 1` instead in that case (it doesn't matter why right now).

Then I can add an if statement in the constructor and in `setA` to check whether the parameter is 0, and set it to 1 in that case. Conceptually, this tells me that in that case I should change the constructor, and instead of initializing `a` there, I should call `setA` in the constructor. In this way, the code for the check is only written once (keep in mind that this a simple situation but the validation could be more complicated in other situations).

Now, that approach involves having an extra function call in the constructor. Is it more efficient to write the validation code twice? What about if `setA` were only to be used sporadically?

Comment: Will probably be inlined anyway, add it in `setA` and call `setA` in constructor. Stop worrying about these (what seems to be but actually aren't) performance differences. Write clean code. The optimizer will do the rest for you.

Comment: You don't need to rename parameters: `A::A(int a) : a(a) { }` is fine.

Comment: @nwp Wow, I did not know that. I was going to ask a language lawyer question to find out when this took place, but apparently this has been a thing for a while: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6185020/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee It's always been allowed in every standard :)

Comment: @GillBates I've already taken advantage of it twice. My code suddenly feels so savvy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your fervor to prevent code duplication. Just be careful of going overboard, a 1-liner might be overboard.

If you're going to do the check though you should use an implementation file function or a `private`, `static` method to do this:

```
int preventZero(const int a_) { return a_ == 0 ? 1 : a_; }
```

Then you can use it in your implementation as follows:

```
A::A(int a_) : a(preventZero(a_)) { }
void A::setA(int a_) { a = preventZero(a_); }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely better to call setter with validation in constructor, because code duplication is evil. You can also make it inlined to make sure you are not wasting CPU cycles, but this is a premature optimization, I think.

Comment: Modern compilers don't listen to `inline`.

Comment: There are compiler-specific attributes to force inlining AFAIK, like __forceinline for VS

Comment: @GillBates Aside from making your code non-portable, `__forceinline` tells the compiler to ignore it's better judgement and use yours. Please refrain from using such `__forceinline`.