# Infinite loop when copying a class containing a BGL graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have a struct (State is a pure virtual abstract class) :

```
    using GraphColorGraph =  boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS,
                                               boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, size_t>>;
    using GraphColorEdge =   boost::graph_traits<GraphColorGraph>::edge_descriptor;
    using GraphColorVertex =  boost::graph_traits<GraphColorGraph>::vertex_descriptor;
    class GraphColor : public State<ZykovMove> {

     private:
      GraphColorGraph graph;
     public:
      GraphColor() = default;
      explicit GraphColor(const GraphColorGraph &graph) : graph(graph) {}
      /*GraphColor(const GraphColor &other): State(other) {
        boost::copy_graph(other.graph, this->graph);
      }
      GraphColor &operator=(const GraphColor &other) {
        boost::copy_graph(other.graph, this->graph);
        return *this;
      }*/
}
```

The problem, I have a function that is destined to be called multiple times (many times!):

```
std::pair<GraphColor, Vertex> expand(const Vertex &not_important, const GraphColor& root , Graph &not_important) const {
      // ... code 
      auto copy_root = root; // infinite loop if copy contructors enabled 
      return make_pair(copy_root, foo) // seg fault if the copy constructors not enabled.
}
```

I have maybe an undefined behavior hide in the code because, when the second call of this function occurs  the copy causes an infinite loop. but if disable copy contructors in `GraphColor` there is no problem copying the `GraphColor` but there is a problem in the make_pair() it produces segfault caused by an InvalidRead (valgrind). In the two calls `root` doesn't change.

Comment: `graph(graph)` -- Why did you name your parameter the same as the member variable?  What happens on that line?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185043/1216776

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, I had undefined behavior because I was storing vertex_descriptor and trying to use it in another graph causing this effect, these vertex_descriptors were invalid.