# Initialise std::function in parent class using member in derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, derived-class, std-function

I have a parent class that looks something like this:

```
class Parent
{
    Parent(std::function<double(double)> func);
};
```

and a derived class that looks something like this:

```
class Derived : public Parent
{
    const double val;

    double MyFunc(double x)
    {
        return x / val;
    }

    Derived(double value)
        : Parent(std::function<double(double)>(&Derived::MyFunc)),
          val(value)
    {
    }
};
```

Basically, I want to restrict `func` from the parent class in a derived class.  I know why what I've done above doesn't work; I've tried various other things like making `MyFunc` `static`; however, this doesn't help because then I can't use `value`, which again, makes sense...

Is there a good way to make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: _"I want to restrict func from the parent class in a derived class"_ I don't know what this sentence means.

Comment: I mean that as it stands, `func` can be anything.  I want to derive a class that mostly, but not fully, defines `func` (I.e. I want to specify what `func` is in a derived class but also have that derived class pass it some parameters).

Comment: Still not clear. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure exactly how to explain, but basically `Parent` is a class that knows how to 'draw' a function (arbitrarily shaped waveguide) in a matrix (the matrix representing a grid of permittivities).  I pass `Parent` the function I want to drawn, and then some other class receives the `Parent` object and draws it.  Now, I want to derive off `Parent` and create a class that always draws sine wave shaped waveguides and accepts a parameter, `val`, that specifying the frequency of the sine wave.

Comment: Okay fine; just make it so the function is not invoked in the `Parent` constructor (which violates several design principles anyway)

Comment: So construct the object without that function, and then call a setter to set it after it has been constructed?  That sounds a bit dodgy.  Perhaps I can just make it pure virtual and create a class to override it everytime I want a new function...  I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: You don't need a setter; you can _set_ the function just fine in the constructor but don't _call_ it there. And why did you want to avoid creating an interface? (which sounds perfect, FYI)

Comment: You can construct the object with "that function", but you cannot call/use "that function" from inside the constructor ... so call it from outside.

Comment: Okay!  Thanks.  And I wanted to avoid the pure virtual approach because I didn't want to constantly have to derive a class every time I wanted to use a different function.  I also wanted it to be possible to, say, just pass in a lambda function.  I probably should've just done the pure virtual thing though...  Something doesn't 'feel' so right about this approach.

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
    : Parent(std::function<double(double)>(&Derived::MyFunc)),
```

to

```
    : Parent(std::bind(&Derived::MyFunc, this, std::placeholders::_1)),
```

Comment: It seems to crash when I do this, I think because `this` hasn't been created when it is trying to initialise the derived class.  It compiles though...

Comment: @Jean-Luc: [This use of `this` is safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5058365/560648). It is impossible to tell why your program is crashing, since you never presented a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Okay, I must be doing something else wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: Why have you accepted this answer when you haven't solved your problem yet? I have no idea what's going on with this question.

Comment: Could [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57ebba9062af496c) be your problem? Only guessing as we have no idea what your program does.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I shouldn't have accepted it.  My mistake.  Yes the problem you've outlined in your example is my issue.  Do you know of a way it could work?  Thank you.

Comment: @Jean-Luc: No, I don't know enough (or, really, _anything_) about what you're trying to do. But it's clear that your base cannot do things with the derived class until the derived class is constructed.

Comment: His question basically was "Is there a way to make this work, so that I can also use `val`". He didn't specify **when** or **how** he wants to use `val` directly or indirectly. So the way I see it, both Jarod42s and my answer are correct for what he asked. The crash problem should maybe be elaborated in another question that provides a full SSCCE.

Comment: @Slyps: Yes, and that lack of specification was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to `std::bind` you may use lambda:

```
Parent([this](int x) { return this->MyFunc(x); })
```