# Using this pointer in an initialization list

Tags: c++, this, initialization-list

I am currently trying to understand if I could use `this` pointer in an initialization list.I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058349/is-it-safe-to-use-the-this-pointer-in-an-initialization-list) SO post which states

> Yes. It's safe to use this pointer in initialization-list as long as
>   it's not being used to access uninitialized members or virtual
>   functions, directly or indirectly, as the object is not yet fully
>   constructed. The object child can store the this pointer of Parent for
>   later use!

So I decided to try this using the following code

```
struct base
{
    int bse;
    base() {
        std::cout << "Base constructor called \n";
    }
};
struct foo
{

    foo() {
        std::cout << "Foo constructor \n";
    }

    foo(int a) {
        std::cout << "Foo parameter \n";
    }
};

struct test : public base
{
    foo a;
    test(int _a) : this->bse(24) , a(_a) {
        std::cout << "test constructor";
    }
};
```

Now from the above example the base class constructor is fully constructed however the base class is still not fully constructed.In the initialization list I am attempting to call an inherited member variables that has been fully constructed.As the link that I already posted mentions that it is safe to use this `pointer`in an initialization list as long as the object being referenced is fully constructed.Please correct me if I misunderstood the quote. So my question is in my case why am I getting the error

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'test::test(int)':
main.cpp:27:20: error: class 'test' does not have any field named 'bse'
     test(int _a) : bse(24) , a(_a) {
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question, because it doesn't matter whether you use `this` for accessing inherited fields or not. It doesn't affect the impossibility to do this.

Comment: The question title is very misleading, since it's not the `this` part that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test(int _a) : this->bse(24) , a(_a) { ... }
```

is not valid since only member variables and base classes can be initialized in the initializer list. Members of base classes cannot be initialized there.

You have to initialize and/or set the value of the `bse` member of the base class using other ways.

1. Provide a constructor in the base class that takes an `int`. Then, you can use:

   ```
   test(int _a) : base(24) , a(_a) { ... }
   ```
2. Set the value in the body of `test()`.

   ```
   test(int _a) : a(_a) { bse = 24; ... }
   ```

Comment: thanks for clearing this up. marked as answer