# Pass derived class members to base class constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have the following piece of code that is working but I don't understand why it works (inspired by a real life code base):

Base class definition:

```
class Pointers {
private:
    int* Obj1;
    double* Obj2;
public:
    Pointers(int* Obj1_, double* Obj2_) : Obj1{Obj1_}, Obj2{Obj2_} {}
};
```

We now derive a class from our base class where we shadow the two pointers with an `int` and a `double` of the same name:

```
class Objects : public Pointers {
public:
    int Obj1{69};
    double Obj2{72};
    Objects() : Pointers(&Obj1, &Obj2) {}
};
```

Within the constructor of `Objects` we call the constructor of `Pointers` and pass the adresses of `Obj1` and `Obj2`. This actually works: The (shadowed) pointers will point to `Obj1 (69)`and `Obj2 (72)`.

My question is: Why is this working? I thought that in the first step the base class members are constructed (which are the two pointers) and only after that the derived class members (the `int` and `double` with the same name) are constructed. How can we pass these objects adresses to the base class constructor in the first place?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This seems to indicate that when the ctor of `Pointers` is called within the ctor of `Objects` it is already known at which adresses in memory the members of the derived class will be?

Comment: @Urwald yes in constructors you can use adresses (or references) of members before they are initialized.

Comment: in this question there are no same names for members and for constructor parameters. Reopnened

Comment: You may not access the objects pointed by Pointers:: Obj1 and Obj2 in Pointers constructor as these are not yet constructed. But as you don't ... nothing is violated.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number There was no need to reopen the question. There are already plenty and plenty of dupes for this. It is about member initializer lists.

Comment: @JasonLiam the proposed dupe was about `Foo::Foo(int x) : x(x)` this question here not. There may be dupes, but not that one

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The fundamental reason is the same. It doesn't have to do anything with parameters. Your answer adds nothing new as you said in your answer *"Obj1 refers to Objects::Obj1."* This is explained by the dupe which says: *"Names in the expression-list of a mem-initializer are evaluated in the scope of the constructor for which the mem-initializer is specified. "*

Comment: I think the main point for me here was why we can use adresses of derived class members in the base class ctor already, not so much the shadowing issue.

Comment: There is such a fuzz about dupe or not dupe and the fact that what OP actually wanted to ask "Why can we use the address of members of an object that is under construction?" gets completely lost in some useless discussion. Its just said.

Comment: fwiw, this is very much related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058349/is-it-safe-to-use-the-this-pointer-in-an-initialization-list. Could be considered as dupe actually. imho its different engouh to not close, but others may think differently

Comment: None of the listed "dupes" answers to question ... the last one is closest but talks specifically about value of this not addresses of not yet constructed data members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, because at the moment when you call your base class constructor, the derived class members

```
    int Obj1{69};
    double Obj2{72};
```

are not yet initialized, but their addresses are already known, and you are using their addresses to initialize pointers in the base class. Note that it has little to do with shadowing.

Of course if you try to print the pointed values in `Pointers` constructor

```
    Pointers(int* Obj1_, double* Obj2_) : Obj1{Obj1_}, Obj2{Obj2_} {
        std::cout << "Obj1: " << *Obj1 << ", Obj2: " << *Obj2 << std::endl;
    }
```

you will get some garbage ([UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)), because pointed to values are not yet initialized. To make the code more clear avoid member fields assignments in the class body, rather use the constructor member initializer list:

```
Objects() : Pointers(&Obj1, &Obj2), Obj1{69}, Obj2{72} {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
class Objects : public Pointers {
public:
    int Obj1{69};
    double Obj2{72};
    Objects() : Pointers(&Obj1, &Obj2) {}
};
```

`Obj1` refers to `Objects::Obj1`. If there is a same named member in `Pointers` then it is shadowed by the member in `Objects`. You need to qualify the name `Pointers::Obj1`. You don't do that, so `Obj1` refers to `Objects::Obj1`. Nothing surprising here.

Then here:

```
class Pointers {
private:
    int* Obj1;
    double* Obj2;
public:
    Pointers(int* Obj1_, double* Obj2_) : Obj1{Obj1_}, Obj2{Obj2_} {}
};
```

Nothing is shadowed, `Obj1_` and `Obj1` are distinct identifiers. The base class initializes its members with the pointers you pass to the constructor.

> This seems to indicate that when the ctor of Pointers is called within the ctor of Objects it is already known at which adresses in memory the members of the derived class will be?

Yes. You can use addresses and references of members of objects that are under construction, before those members are initialized. As long as you do not dereference the pointer (or try to read the member's value via the reference) all is fine. For example the code would invoke undefined behavior, if in the base constructors body you would add some `std::cout << *Obj1;`, because the `int` pointed to by `Obj` is not initialized at that point.

Comment: There was no need to reopen the question. There are plenty and plenty of dupes for this. Your answer says: *"Obj1 refers to Objects::Obj1..."* This is already explained in the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185020/initializing-member-variables-using-the-same-name-for-constructor-arguments-as-f) : *"Names in the expression-list of a mem-initializer are evaluated in the scope of the constructor for which the mem-initializer is specified."*

Answer (score 2):

The initialization of the class actually proceeds as follows:

1. Determine the memory that's used to construct the object (e.g. stack location or use of the result of the `new` operator).
2. Enter call of `Object::Object()`
3. `Pointers::Pointers(int* Obj1_, double* Obj2_)` gets called. *This happens before any initializers for the members of `Object` are executed.* The memory locations are already available though (see step 1.), so the address-of operator can be used.
4. Initialization of `Pointers` part of the object completes
5. The member variables of `Object` are initialized.

Note simply that simply passing the address of member variables can be done, but you need to make sure the pointers are not dereferenced in the base class constructor, since this would result in undefined behaviour.